# Is there any solution for this azure datafactory error?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am facing below datafactory error while lodaing data from sql server to blob by using data factory.Can anyone give some inputs on this issue?

{
"errorCode": "2100",
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Reference to database and/or server name in 'demo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Reference to database and/or server name in 'demo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=40515,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=40515,State=1,Message=Reference to database and/or server name in 'demo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.,},],'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "ListTablesIn sql",
"details": []
}

Answer (score 0):

Please use **Query** operation to get the data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:
[image]

Or set the schema with INFORMATION_SCHEMA and table name: TABLES in Source dataset:
[image]

I tested and it all works well in my Azure SQL database.

**Update:**

Congratulations that you resolved the issue by choose database in linked service.

Comment: Hi yue, we need to choose database in linked service.I have resolved issue my self.Appreciating your help.

Comment: @shoyab you're welcome. May I add this to my answer? Then others can know your issue is resolved!  you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. You also could post it by yourself. Thank you again and  have a good day!

Comment: Sure yue,you can.